# typeerror when running a fetch function before form submission

Tags: javascript, html, maps, fetch, geocode

I got this **error**:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
```

when trying to run `*geocodeAddress*()`.

If I run the same exact code outside of that function without `onsubmit=""`, it works and logs the data to the console. Why is this?

```
<?php 

// ...

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/maps.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="info" action="private/database.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return geocodeAddress()"> 
      <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="性氏" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="given_name" placeholder="名字" required><br>
      <label for="male">
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" required>
        男性
      </label>
      <label for="female">
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender">
        女性
      </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="電子信箱" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="電話" required><br>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="地址" required><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="latlng">
      <input type="date" name="cleaning_date" required><br>
      <input type="submit" name="form_submit">

      <script>
        function geocodeAddress() {
          fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyDxn8WYv2aE5UrrufXLqeXKVYUnD-VyReA')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    </script>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try passing function reference to onsubmit instead of "return geocodeAddress()" use onsubmit="geocodeAddress"

Comment: @Shreyashbhatt still getting the same error, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

solved:
the error went away after I changed it to

```
onsubmit="geocodeAddress(event.preventDefault())"
```